# Spring Security for multiuser Spring MVC web app

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a web app using SpringMVC. The app should manage several users with these traditional operations (for each user) :  registration- login - logout - update account - etc...

So, my questions are:
Is Spring Security enough to manage these operations for several users ?

What is the best way to proceed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what spring security meant for, it will work like a charm.

Follow this link for a simple example.

http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/

Comment: Thanks for the link it's a nice example but unfortunately I prefer the configuration with an xml file. It's more readable than a Java configuration.